# Rigid bodies animation failing to contain spheres within a moving box

Tags: particles, physics

I am animating a drone carrying spheres inside a container. I also have a turbulance force moving in order to give the effect of levitating balls. There is no gravity in the scene. The idea is to create the effect of balls being carried within a box with air from top and bottom.

I tried everything I had in mind and I could research online. My substeps and iterations are both at 100 in the rigid world. The box, top lid and bottom one are all set as rigid body passive and have the animated box checked.

[image: Screenshot of the balls failing to be contained]

I can share the scene if its needed.
Thank you

Comment: Sharing your blend file would be ideal, https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: @NascentSpace I uploaded it now via your link :)

Comment: Send me the link to it and I'll check it out

Comment: @NascentSpace its funny, but did not give me any link...Can I send you a wetransfer link?

Comment: This is what I get [img]https://i.imgur.com/Cb6vMjl.jpg[/img]

Comment: @bruno: follow the instructions at  blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com -> you have to copy the link you will get in here...

Comment: @NascentSpace Thats what I did. The link does not pop. In the help section its written that sometimes it does not work.